# how to wrap a html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why won't this jquery object of `p` tags get wrapped by the `div`. I know the documentation says that it must be a dom element but there has to be a way?

WHY DOES IT ONLY ALERT test1?

http://jsfiddle.net/scwonubb/

```
    var s = '<p>test1</p><p>test2</p><p>test3</p><p>test4</p><p>test5</p><p>test6</p><p>test</p>';

    var $d = $(s).wrapAll('<div class="mydiv">'); 


    var final = $d.html();
alert(final);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you variable `$d` is the jQuery object of your variable `s` even if you have wrapped it. Try alerting the parent, it will be the `div` :

```
var final = $d.parent().html();
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scwonubb/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply. is it possible to include the div in the text that is alerted?  I need to toString the html?

Comment: @Hello-World you can use `$d.parent()[0].outerHTML;`

Answer (score 2):

`.html()` gets the *contents* of what you have selected.

Change it to `$d.parent().html()` and it will work.